# How to track the uploading process on firebase with flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, video-upload

I have this future function that will upload a video to firebase, I want to track this uploading process in percentage, so after the uploading process is completed, I will get the url.

**Code**

```
Future storageupload() async {
    try {
      if (controller = null) {
        dialog('Error', 'Please Provide A Video Name', () => {});
      } else {
        StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child("Khatma 1")
            .child("Videos")
            .child(controller.text != null ? controller.text : "");
        StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
            File(Variables.lastVideoPath),
            StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future uploadToStorage() async {
    try {
      await storageupload();
      final downloadUrl = await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("Khatma 1")
          .child('Videos')
          .child(controller.text)
          .getDownloadURL();

      final String url = downloadUrl.toString();

      print(url);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check this article https://dev.to/happyharis/flutter-web-firebase-storage-2ac1

Comment: but I am using flutter on apps not web.

Comment: I think this might be the [solution] (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20803#issuecomment-427664938)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get by listening to `TaskSnapshot` Stream.

```
uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
      double _progress = snapshot.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / snapshot.totalBytes.toDouble();
    });
```

For more info: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageTaskSnapshot-class.html

If you are using an older version of Firebase storage i.e `snapshotEvents` is not available.

This should work for you.

```
uploadTask.events.listen((event) {
  double _progess = event.snapshot.bytesTransferred.toDouble()  / event.snapshot.totalByteCount.toDouble();
});
```

Comment: you mean `lastSnapshot`

Comment: because there is no `snapshotEvents`

Comment: Which version of Firebase storage are you running?
Because the latest version of Firebase storage replaces `events` with `snapshotEvents`, so, `events` is depricated.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/

Comment: ok, I actually don't like to update to latest version as some big changes occurred and I will go and change a lot of changes in my app plus I have to test them as they may not work as they should work.

Comment: I have updated the answer for the older version as well. Hope it helps.